# Graphics.CopyFromScreen() and GetDC(0) fail with "The handle is invalid"

Tags: c#, c++, screenshot

I have an application that takes screenshots from the local computer.
This works since many years correctly until suddenly a colleague reported me that he got an "The handle is invalid" error from my application.

This error came from inside the .NET framework from `Graphics.CopyFromScreen()`.

To work around this I replaced this function with C++ code using `GetDC(GetDesktopWindow())` / `GetDC(NULL)` and `BitBlt()` to copy the screen into a bitmap. Now I got `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`.

This happens on Windows 7.

What is going on there ?
I can not investigate this problem on my own because I cannot reproduce it and my colleague is in another country.

I searched in Google and lots of people report this error.
But all posts that I found were from people who tried to take a screenshot from a client computer through ASP code on a server. I don't understand how people can have the strange desire to capture the client's computer from a website. It is obvious that this will not work.

But I could not find one single case where someone reports this problem from an application that cannot capture the screen of the SAME computer in the SAME session where the application itself is running.

Comment: This exception is almost always caused by a handle leak, the program falls over when the OS prevents the process from creating more or the desktop heap is exhausted. Pretty diagnosable with Task Manager, Processes tab. Use View > Select Columns and tick USER Objects and GDI Objects.   Steadily climbing numbers spell doom.

Comment: It seems you did not read my answer.

Comment: Remote desktop sessions share your screen. That means that when you for example minimize the remote desktop application, there is no screen to capture anymore. Are you sure the issue is actually happening *all* the time? It should work fine when you're properly connected and when the remote desktop application is visible and active. Perhaps you just need to handle the failure gracefully and resume operation when you get the screen back again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After investigating more with my colleague and giving him ideas what he can try, he told me that he starts my application through a remote desktop session.

The remote desktop session creates a virtual desktop (you see for example that the desktop wallpaper is missing).

I told my colleague to install a VNC client to remote control the computer instead of a remote desktop session and now all works fine. He installed TightVNC which uses the REAL desktop user session instead of creating a virtual session and locking the screen of the machine.

So if anyone gets reports of "The handle is invalid" while taking a screen capture, ask your users if they use a remote desktop session.

To detect a remote desktop session in code you can write:

in C++:

```
if (GetSystemMetrics(SM_REMOTESESSION) > 0)
{
    MessageBox(m_hWnd, L"This application may not work correctly in a remote desktop session", "Error", MB_ICONSTOP);
}
```

or in C#:

```
if (System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession)
{
    Messagebox.Show("This application may not work correctly in a remote desktop session");
}
```

Note that the problem is not reproducible on all computers. When I test on my own Windows 7 it works. So there are probably any additional system settings or other factors that trigger the "The handle is invalid" error (service packs / hotfixes...?).

But my colleague reports that he has never seen the error again after he stopped using the remote desktop connection.

Comment: I'm not the writer of TightVNC. But if there is someone searching for an alternative to a remote desktop session, why not immediately give him a solution that is proven to work ? I cannot see what is wrong to cite a working solution. I'm not sure if all VNC clients work the same way.

Comment: It seems that you don't know that TightVNC is freeware and open source. Why should anybody waste his time to give software recommendations on StackOverflow to promote a freeware program?

Comment: OK. To finish this discussion: I'am not involved in the TighVNC development and I'm not interested to promote it. I just mentioned it for those who need a well working VNC program to save these people the time for googling around. It would be really sad if Stackoverflow would punish me for giving a good hint. Stackoverflow has been made to help others and that is what I was doing.

Comment: I can confirm that this problem happens on remote desktop, but it's not machine dependent. In my setup it some times happens and some times not (same machine, same program, same setup, same day, same boot, etc.). Tested with Windows Server 2019 Standard.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few reasons this can happen but the underlying theme is that the desktop window isn't available when this method is called.

In addition to the reasons mentioned above, another reason this can happen is if this method is being called when the screen is locked.

The code for CopyFromScreen has this section:

```
int result = SafeNativeMethods.BitBlt(targetDC, destinationX, destinationY, destWidth, destHeight, screenDC, sourceX, sourceY, (int) copyPixelOperation); 

//a zero result indicates a win32 exception has been thrown
if (result == 0) { 
    throw new Win32Exception();
}
```

It would seem to me that the safest course of action would be that if you make use of this function, make sure that you also write your code assuming that receiving a Win32Exception or an unavailable Desktop Window is a use case which must be handle so the application doesn't crash.